# Cheap crypto miner to for beginners

Tags: cheap

I want to try out mining for the first time, im looking for a miner (possibly ASIC) that would be around 500 dollars.
I dont need something profitable 1-2 dollars daily is fine for me.

Anyone know what i can start with?

EDIT:
I found this rig: https://tinyurl.com/33rukevh
Is it worth it?

Comment: For beginners, graphics cards are probably better than ASICs, since they have resell value, ASICs don't.

Comment: What can i start with?

Comment: I don't know too much about cryptomining, but the items in your edit kinda look OK. Do mind you will need to do some underclocking and undervolting to make it work

Comment: You were looking at at under $1000 in your previous question. That rig would cost you **8** grand & you'd *still* have a GPU rig.

Comment: Thats still without gpu

Comment: I know, i didnt say it had to be ASIC, you said a GPU rig would be better, Irsu85